# How to take advantage of variables whose values are available in the past but not in the future?

Tags: predictive-modeling

Example: weather data. You know the location data, but you don't know the previous days'/weeks' temperatures and other weather conditions. How can you exploit these variables in your past data when you build a predictive model that attempts to forecast pretty far out into the future?

Comment: I can answer the titular question but I don't follow the example. You want the forecast the weather using the historical location but not the actual temperature at that location?

Comment: @Emre I do want to use the actual temperature at that location, but suppose I want to predict the mean temperature on November 1st 2016, then I don't have the temperature on October 31st 2016 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My generic answer to the title is to use the extra data for [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) in [representation learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_learning); a transformation of your features into a space conducive to your main task: regression (prediction, forecasting). [Here's](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2013.50) a survey [[PDF](http://www.cifasis-conicet.gov.ar/granitto/ECI2014/Bengio13.pdf)].

For your example, you could build a model that takes the delay of the target time from the present as an input, so you can predict arbitrarily far into the future, though it probably would not predict as well as a simple regressor that has a fixed horizon since it is trying to learn a more complex function.